# What are the black boots on this Extra 300's prop?

Tags: propeller, feature-identification, extra-aircraft

I normally think of black boots on a prop as being for de-icing. However, the Extra 300 is not suitable for known-icing conditions, or even IMC flight. (It's AFM says "Only VFR flights at day are allowed").

Considering the Extra 300's aerobatic mission, the gyroscopic loads on the engine are fierce. The upshot is that the manufacturer would not include a single extra gram more than necessary here.

So why are they there/what do they do? It has the owner and I stumped.

[image]

Comment: Since you're in contact with the owner, they can touch and feel the black section -- does it feel like plastic/rubber, or paint?

Comment: Interesting question. Doing a Google image search for extra 300 propelller shows that many (but not all) have the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The inner portion of the blade is protected by a **self-adhesive PU-strip,** unless the blade is equipped with a de-ice boot.

The outboard edge as you can see in the very lower-right corner is protected with a stainless steel erosion sheath. Since the inboard section is slower (radial speed), its protection is a lighter polyurethane-strip/tape.

> [image]

The Extra 300's service manual lists the 3-blade prop as one of two MTV-9 series (you can see the MT logo already in your photo). The above quote and illustration are from the MTV-9 series operation manual from [mt-propeller.com](https://www.mt-propeller.com/en/entw/serv_op.htm). An example tape is the [3M 8663HS](https://www.google.com/search?q=3M+8663HS&tbm=isch), which comes in black or transparent.